# Why this error comes as per i upload multiple images?

Tags: image, upload

When i upload multiple images from my code, everything is uploaded to mysql database, but displays error with saying success : 
I just don't want this error.[Error is :Notice: Undefined variable: user_id in C:\wamp\www\swaminarayant\multiple_file_up.php on line 13]
 Can anyone help me out of this? 
My code is:

```
<?php include 'connect.php';?>
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }   
$query="INSERT into upload_data (`USER_ID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
$desired_dir="user_data";
if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
     mysql_query($query);           
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
}?
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: By "but displays error with saying success" do you mean it shows you just the word 'success'?... because thats what you prointing out by your echo if there have not been any errors. If its not that you can remove print_r($errors) i assume or better configure php.ini to not display errors at all.

Comment: Yes, ever i remove: print_r($errors) , it display same error : 
as:

Notice: Undefined variable: user_id in C:\wamp\www\swaminarayant\multiple_file_up.php on line 13
Success

Comment: Ah, sorry overread that, see my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your Code around Line 13:

```
$query="INSERT into upload_data (`USER_ID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES 
('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
```

Within the VALUES part you try to include a variable $user_id which was never defined above. 
Youre setting the other values properly:

```
$file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
$file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
$file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
```

But you are missing a definition for $user_id. If you insert for example:

```
$user_id = "foo";
```

Or

```
$user_id = 1;
```

In case it must be a number you should be all good.

Comment: I set to 
$user_id= '';
and now it works well. 
Thank you for your clue.